# Uninstall Mylyn from Eclipse Luna

Tags: uninstallation, eclipse-luna, mylyn

Found plenty of instructions that tell me to do this: Go to Help → Software Updates → Manage Configuration and uninstall it there (they all seem to point to the Mylyn site's instructions). But in Luna the menu has changed. It has "Check for updates" which doesn't have the Manage Configuration option, and "Installation Details." Installation details only allows uninstallation from the Installed Software tab, and Mylyn does not appear there. How does one remove Mylyn from Luna? I would like to avoid uninstalling manually if possible.

[image]

Comment: Mylyn is probably a child feature of one of the features you have installed and therefore it [cannot be uninstalled independently](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435681#c1). I have created [eclipse bug 455289](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455289) on this issue.

Comment: The bug 455289 has been resolved "invalid"... do you know what's the deal then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this blog entry where they want a "lean mean Eclipse machine" without SVN support, Mylyn, and all the other stuff I never use: http://www.martijndashorst.com/blog/2014/07/07/custom-eclipse-luna/
Edit: the above link no longer works.

Unfortunately, in the end they just point you to https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/, which once was a free, but now is a quite expensive service where you can customize your Eclipse install.

Comment: Unfortunately Yoxos has in no way a free plan. And plans start at $300/month... too bad!

Comment: True: rather unfortunate. Yoxos decided to multiply their prices with 8. It used to be well worth the price–even considering there were some bugs. However our company can't sustain a 800% price increase for this product, so we didn't renew our license and return to manually maintain our Eclipse installatations. We are hoping OOMPH--Eclipse's new installer framework--will solve our needs with Eclipse Mars.

Comment: link to martijndashorst.com is broken.